# Formatting DataFrame Object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and trying to pull a table from a wiki page into a pandas dataframe. I am using the `wikipediaapi` to retrieve the URL for the site. (Is there a way to pull the table directly using the api instead of pandas?). Also noteworthy I am trying to use the method as described [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/2-easy-ways-to-get-tables-from-a-website-with-pandas-b92fc835e741).

Below is my current code:

```py
#packages
import wikipediaapi as wpa
import pandas as pd

#get page url
wiki_page = wpa.Wikipedia('en')
page_py = wiki_page.page('Python_(programming_language)')
page_url = page_py.fullurl
#print(page_url)

page_tables = pd.read_html(page_url)[1]

#print(page_tables)

sum_table_df = pd.DataFrame(data=page_tables)

print("page_tables type: ", type(page_tables))
print("sum_table_df type: ", type(page_tables))
print(sum_table_df)
```

Output:

> page_tables type:  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

> sum_table_df type:  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

[image]

My problem is that the output has not printed out as a normal dataframe would (table formatting). Not sure what I have done incorrectly? Red underlines are the headers for each column..

Comment: Are you using Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: @JaroslavBezděk yes sir, I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/) and you want your data frame to be formatted as table, do not use `print()` function to print you data frame. Just run the cell with the name of your data frame, like this:

```
In [1]: sum_table_df
Out[1]: your formatted data frame
```